# Why is my Google Analytics event tracking code not working from a PHP script called from my Flash movie?

Tags: php, javascript, flash, google-analytics

I have a flash movie that calls a PHP script, passing a variable for this PHP script to process. I want to track this in google analytics.

So my PHP script looks like this -

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("analyticstracking.php");
?>
<script>
   _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Cat', 'Event', 'label', <?php echo($variable); ?>]);
</script>
```

Heres my analyticstracking.js script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-#######-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowAnchor', true]); 
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageLoadTime'])
  _gaq.push(['_setSessionCookieTimeout', 3600000]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

When I use Firebug to try and detect the call to google analytics I dont see the usual _utm.gif image that I do on other pages so I dont think this event is being tracked.

So my questions are -

1. Is there a problem including the google analytics script in a separate file?
2. Is this not working because my PHP file doesnt have the usual  tags?
3. Is this not working because it is being called from Flash?

or none of the above and something else Ive missed?

thanks all.

Comment: Put a `console.log()` in the JS inside your PHP file to see if that JS is every executed.

Comment: Thanks, I added console.log("hello world") between my <script> tags in the php file and it is not getting called - I dont see any hello world output when I look at the console in firebug. Actually my javasscript is inside a foreach and an if statement - would this make any difference? When I look at the response tab for this page in the net window of firebug it shows me the javascript.

Comment: It is opening this PHP script in a pop up window right? If called directly from Flash then the JS in the response will not be executed as Flash just treats the response as a string.

Comment: No, not opening the PHP in a pop up window. this must be what is wrong.. I will have to find another way of tracking the event. Why dont you post an answer and I can accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: done. Hopefully useful too! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash will interpret the value returned from the PHP file as a string. It will not evaluate the javascript.

You have two options really:

1. Open a popup with the PHP code in it
2. Trigger Google Analytics events from within Flash using something like [gaforflash](http://code.google.com/p/gaforflash/)